# Spring Maven War Project Not Deploying to Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to Deploy my Maven Web Project in the Tomcat Server in Eclipse. However, it's not displaying the "War" project under the selected project. Any Idea what I am missing?

[image]

Solution: Add  in the org.eclipse.wst.common.component file where the war file is located

Comment: Could you elaborate the error? In the picture above, the red warning is against removal of the project. Click on Finish and post that error if anything comes up.

Comment: That Red Warning has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do. I am trying to deploy the War file in the Tomcat. When I select the Project, it must have the War file included in it. I have marked the project with the Red Box. Under it, it should display the War File as well.

Comment: does your project have a web.xml and is that class path

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created dynamic web project (or spring mvc project) and  you must have web.xml file .

Then make sure you have following entries in your maven. I mean maven-war-plugin .

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```